# Is there any package which ships a systemd preset file along with the service?

Tags: linux, systemd

I found the following from [the systemd.preset man page](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) —

> It is not recommended to ship preset files within the respective software packages implementing the units, but rather centralize them in a distribution or spin default policy, which can be amended by administrator policy.

I could not find any package specific preset files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset` on my machine.

Does any software exist which ship such preset files along with the package? Such rpm will install preset file into `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset`. (Apart from the default systemd and distribution preset files).

Answer (score 2):

On Arch Linux, use `pkgfile`:

```
# pkgfile -u
$ pkgfile -v -g "/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/*"
core/systemd 232-4  /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-systemd.preset
core/systemd 232-4  /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/99-default.preset
```

On Debian or Ubuntu, use `apt-file`:

```
# apt-file update
$ apt-file search /lib/systemd/system-preset
systemd: /lib/systemd/system-preset/90-systemd.preset
zfsutils-linux: /lib/systemd/system-preset/50-zfs.preset
```

Comment: Have you encountered any popular software which copies a preset file into `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset` upon rpm insallation? (Apart from the default systemd and distribution preset files).

Comment: @nithinj clearly `zfsutils-linux` does.

Comment: Presets kind of _are_ a distribution thing though...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @grawity's answer above, on Centos, use `yum whatprovides`:

```
yum whatprovides "/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/*"
```